# How to disable or uninstall printscreen feature in ubuntu

Tags: print-screen

I am using Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.5 Desktop which comes with Gnome3. I am trying to disable the printscreen feature systemwide for all users by uninstalling `gnome-screenshot` and moving the `gdm-screenshot` binary from `/usr/bin/` but still the printsrc button works and saves the screenshot in my pictures directory.

Please advise me how to disable this.

Comment: I removed the gnome-screenshot already.

Comment: Is changing the default directory to, say, a user-restricted directory, viable?

Comment: Why do you wanna disable it?

Comment: You need to make clear that you are talking about users on separate machines. These answers all assume you meant on ONE machine. And the answer is (a) Disable in the keyboard settings (if it works - it doesnt in Debian Buster as of today). or uninstall gnome-screenshot. This would need to be done on ALL users machines.

Answer (score 0):

**To Disable:**

Remove executable permission from `gnome-screenshot`

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/bin/gnome-screenshot
```

Now print-screen disabled, if you want to get it work back just change from `-x` to `+x`

---

**To Remove Complete:**

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gnome-screenshot
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove gnome-screenshot
```

Comment: Hi Benny, We have 100s of ubuntu desktops in our organization and ~300 users using it. So it is not practically possible to go to every user profile on each system to disable this feature. Since this is a security feature, none of the user should be able to enable this feature by themselves.

Comment: Is there any commandline uitlity to disable this feature systemwide for all users.

Comment: this edited solution good for you?

Comment: Hi Benny, gnome-screenshot itself is not there under /usr/bin after uninstalling the gnome-screenshot package. This is what the exact problem is, even after removing the gnome-screenshot package the printscr button is working. Is there any key-map feature to be disable this systemwide?

Comment: so just reinstall `gnome-screenshot` and remove executable permission. users will not be able to use this app and not the keyboard button.

Comment: Benny, I tried reinstalling the gnome-screenshot and removed the execute permission for all the users. But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to disable printscreen feature systemwide, via gsettings

Have the below gsettings commands in a .sh file and place it under /etc/profile.d/

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot 'Disabled'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot 'Disabled'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys area-screenshot-clip 'Disabled'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys screenshot-clip 'Disabled'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot 'Disabled'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys window-screenshot-clip 'Disabled'
```

logoff and login again for the settings to get effect.